# Make table in android studio half the height of the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, responsive

Basically, I have a table with a bunch of buttons and I've realized that the height stays fixed on multiple screen sizes. Is there a unit for height that is a percentage of the screen size or is there some other way? Here's the XML for the table.
So right now, I want the height of the table to be half the screen size it's on. On most pixel devices, it's fine, but for tablets on portrait mode, it's only a 4th of the screen. The height for the table layout rn is wrap content but im fine if u can change it.

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clearBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff4757"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_medium"
                android:onClick="clearBTN"
                android:text="@string/clear"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff4757" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/paranthesisBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff4757"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_medium"
                android:onClick="paranthesisBTN"
                android:text="@string/parantheses"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff4757" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exponentBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff4757"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_medium"
                android:onClick="exponentBTN"
                android:text="@string/exponent"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff4757" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/divideBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff4757"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_medium"
                android:onClick="divideBTN"
                android:text="@string/divide"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff4757" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sevenBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="sevenBTN"
                android:text="@string/seven"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eightBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="eightBTN"
                android:text="@string/eight"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nineBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="nineBTN"
                android:text="@string/nine"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/multiplyBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff9500"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="multiplyBTN"
                android:text="@string/multiply"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff9500" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fourBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="fourBTN"
                android:text="@string/four"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fiveBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="fiveBTN"
                android:text="@string/five"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sixBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="sixBTN"
                android:text="@string/six"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/subtractBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff4757"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="subtractBTN"
                android:text="@string/subtract"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff9500" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/oneBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="oneBTN"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/twoBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="twoBTN"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/threeBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="threeBTN"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff4757"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="addBTN"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff9500" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plusMinusButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="plusMinusBTN"
                android:text="@string/plusMinus"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/zeroBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="zeroBTN"
                android:text="@string/zero"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pointBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                android:onClick="pointBTN"
                android:text="@string/point"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#505050" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/equalsBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:onClick="equalsBTN"
                android:text="@string/equals"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#ff9500" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common strategies for getting a percentage of the screen (or really, of the parent layout):

- Use `LinearLayout` plus `layout_weight`
- Use `ConstraintLayout` plus `Guideline`

#### LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ...>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here we combine a height of `0dp` with a weight of `1` on both views. This will cause the space to be split evenly between the two, and since the first view is a `Space` (invisible view), the outcome will be the table being half of the screen.

You can use any value you want for weight. If you wanted 66% of the screen, you would give the Space a weight of `1` and the TableLayout a weight of `2`; the ratio is all that matters.

#### ConstraintLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
    
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ...>

    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here we put a `Guideline` (an invisible "anchor") into the ConstraintLayout. By setting its percent to `0.5`, we put it right in the middle of the screen. After that, we just position the TableLayout relative to the guideline.

If you wanted to make the table larger or smaller, all you'd have to do is move the guideline.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the table rows. There are 5. Any way to make each row 1/5 of the table's height?

Comment: `TableLayout` is just a specialized (vertical) `LinearLayout`, which means you can use `layout_weight` on its children too. Change each row to `<TableRow android:layout_weight="1">` and they should each get 1/5 of the space in the table.

Comment: Oh, but one last thing. doing android:layout_weight="1" stretches the rows apart. I mean I wanted the buttons to get taller to fit in the table.

Comment: Once the rows are stretched, you can set the buttons to use `match_parent` for their height.

Comment: yes, yes. Sorry. I came now to say nevermind. Thanks so much

Comment: Hi again. You answered my question yesterday but I have another issue. I came to you because you probably know how to answer it. So please take a look:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023264/background-image-stretches-to-fit-on-android-screen